# php perl cross-platform encoder/decoder

Tags: php, perl, encryption, php-7

it used to be that the perl encoder

```
use Crypt::CBC;
$cipher= Crypt::CBC->new( {'key' => $cipherkey,
             'cipher'=> 'Blowfish',
             'iv' => '12345678',
             'regenerate_key' => 0,
             'padding' => 'null',
             'prepend_iv' => 0
            });
```

could be nicely decrypted by the php function

```
mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, base64_decode($v), MCRYPT_DECRYPT, '12345678')
```

alas, mcrypt_cbc is not only deprecated now, it also disappeared from php7 altogether.

is there a recommended encoder in perl that the standard new php decoder mcrypt_encrypt works with?

for my purposes, I do not need to be super-secret.  reasonably secret is ok.  no life-or-death secrets.  if it takes half an hour to decode, it's good enough.  ideally, I would use whatever the canonical security encoder decoder is (as long as they are compatible, of course).

advice appreciated.

Comment: By the way, using a constant IV is not as good as using a random one.

Comment: ikegami---thanks for the answer.  mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, base64_decode($v), "cbc", '12345678')) is a good substitute.  can you answer the question, please, so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs point out you should use `mcrypt_decrypt` instead. It appears PHP is phasing out `mcrypt_cbc` in favour of a more generic interface. The following provides the same functionality:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, base64_decode($cipher_base64), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```